# tomcat putting file in different host

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

let say my main apps is in

```
http://localhost:8080/web or /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/web
```

and i create an empty host in

```
http://localhost:8080/cdn or /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/cdn
```

this empty host supposed to put all the uploaded file. In the main app, i've prepared module to upload file and i want to put it in cdn folder from java web code. but how to get the real path of http://localhost:8080/cdn ?

how to access the cdn host?

Comment: try to use relative path ../cdn . Edit this path as per the location of your HTMP in the web application.

Comment: are u saying like this ? String path = servletContext.getRealPath("../cdn");

Comment: Is cdn is any web application or just a folder?

Comment: its a folder in webapps, so its should be able as webapps

Comment: See just creating a folder in webapps will not make it a webapp. So one approach is to normally create a webapp cdn. Expose a servlet in it and call this to upload your file. Otherwise if you just need to upload file to a directory then create a folder at your desired location and write your file in that location.